# How to union tables with different schema in HIVE?

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql, union-all

I have two tables in HIVE:

- table A, which contains a column "N" which is of type array
- table B, in which column "N" does not appear

both tables A and B contain column "C".

I'd like to union them like this:

```
select g.* from 

(select N, C from A
union all
select null as N, C from B
) g;
```

but this throws an error in HIVE:

```
FAILED:...Schema of both sides of union should match: Column N is of type array<string> on first table and type void on second table.
```

So, I tried to convert the datatypes:

```
select g.* from 

(select N, C from A
union all
select cast(null as array) as N, C from B
) g;
```

This fails with `"cannot recognize input near 'array' ')' 'as' in primitive type specification.`

How do I solve this? Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.  There is probably an easier way, but I'm not sure how to express a `NULL` array constant in Hive.  You can use SQL for this:

```
select g.*
from (select N, C from A
      union all
      select A.N, C
      from B join
           A 
           on 1 = 0
     ) g;
```

In other words, I may not know how to express the constant off the top of my head.  But, I can arrange to get it from `A` -- by failing to match to a row.

Comment: will this be slow because of the `join`?

Comment: @Candic3 . . . To be honest, I do not know.  Other databases would be pretty smart about the join, but Hive may not be.  You can always do something like `(select A.* from A limit 1)` -- which should be pretty fast.